# Update Label outside of RadAjaxPanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I want to update a Label(`lbltest`) by `RadGrid ItemCommand` (`frmRptControlledUsers`) event. The Label is outside of `RapControlledUsers` but RadGrid is inside that.

**Html Markup**

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RALPPermissions" runat="server" EnableSkinTransparency="true" BackgroundTransparency="30">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RapControlledUsers" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RALPPermissions">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="frmRptControlledUsers" RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server">
        <mastertableview>
            <columns>
                <telerik:gridtemplatecolumn>
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
                            Delete
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </itemtemplate>
                </telerik:gridtemplatecolumn>
            </columns>
        </mastertableview>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
<asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void RptControlledUsers_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string Command = e.CommandName.ToString();
    switch (Command.ToLower())
    {
        case "delete":
            {
                this.lbltest.Text="this is updated";
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Comment: If you are using an AjaxManager on your master page, consider using an ajax proxy. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajaxmanager/how-to/radajax-and-masterpage

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a couple of options here.

1. Use `RadAjaxManager` control instead of `RadAjaxPanel`

   ```
   <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="AjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
   <AjaxSettings>
       <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="frmRptControlledUsers">
           <UpdatedControls>
               <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lbltest" />
           </UpdatedControls>
       </telerik:AjaxSetting>
   </AjaxSettings>
   ```
2. Use `ScriptManager` to manually register the control. `ScriptManager.RegisterDataItem()`. Please check these links for more details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301423(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

https://abhijitjana.net/2010/06/14/how-to-update-controls-which-are-outside-of-updatepanel-during-partial-page-rendering/